# emacs copy text after symbol in each line

Tags: regex, emacs

I have a block of text that looks something like

```
par.dm_std;
par.dm_POM;
par.dm_CaCO3;
```

and I want it to look like

```
par.dm_std = dm_std;
par.dm_POM = dm_std;
par.dm_CaCO3 = dm_CaCO3;
```

So I am essentially trying to copy everything after the "." and put an equals sign before and a semicolon afterward. I tried to run a query replace with

```
par\.\(.*\) -> par\.\1 = \1;
```

but then emacs returns the error message

```
Invalid use of `\' in replacement text
```

I can't figure out for the life of me what I am doing wrong here?
By the way, this is matlab code I am working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not escape `.` in the replacement text. You also should have a literal `;` at the end of the match expression; otherwise, it will be included in `\1` and you'll get an extra semicolon before the equal sign.

```
Replace regexp: par\.\(.*\);
Replace with: par.\1 = \1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I should have used replace-regex rather than query-replace-regex.
With the former, everything just works.

Comment: They both do replacements identically. The only difference is that `query-replace-regexp` asks before doing each replacement.